# Video Background Autoplay not working on Mobile (Wordpress)

Tags: android, html, ios, wordpress, video

I am trying to get a background video to play when a user visit the homepage of my wordpress website, however, the video only autoplays when visiting the desktop version. Also, when I preview the website via wordpress using the device VM it shows it is autoplaying, but when I visit the domain website on my mobile device it does not autoplay.

Is it possible that you are unable to autoplay a video on mobile devices?

The javascript below checks to see if the user is using a moblie device or desktop. If the user is using a mobile device the mobile friendly version of the video will display, otherwise the desktop version will display:

```
<script> 
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)  
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)  
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) 
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) { 
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) { $('body').prepend('<div class="video-bg-container"><video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline class="bg-video"><source src="MOB-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>'); });
}else { 
   jQuery(document).ready( function($) { $('body').prepend('<div class="video-bg-container"><video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline class="bg-video"><source src="DSK.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>'); });
}

</script>
```

Any information you might have on the topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

I am running the tests on an IPhone 11 Max Pro. Here is the Codec Information. The file is MP4 with H264.

[image]

Comment: Mobile browsers, to conserve data-usage, don't allow autoplaying of videos; at least, that's what I read a few months ago.  My advice would be, thinking of your users' experience and data plans, to replace the video with an image.  However, there are a series of rules and parameters you have to ensure are addressed if you still want to get autoplay to work on those devices that will allow it: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/  That's an example, but you'll have to search through the other browsers to see what their rules are.

Comment: All mobile browsers support autoplay.  What device are you testing on?

Does the mobile video work on your desktop?  Does the mobile video play if you add controls and try to start it on your mobile device?  

My gut feeling is that the container is mp4, but the encoding is not h264, but rather vp8 or vp9, and you are testing on an Apple device (which does not support those codecs).

Check the codec with ffprobe (here's an API version https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=yourVideoURL) and report back the encoding.

Comment: I am testing on the IPhone 11 Max Pro. It does not play if I add controls. The mobile video does work on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You must also enable autoPlay inside the video tag.

Note that if you are using iphone, the autoplay feature is disabled if you are in battery saving mode

Answer (score 1):

new to coding websites but when i had the same issue on my static html website i found the solution on here. Basically on mobile, videos do not autoplay unless they are muted. The code that helped is below.

```
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="video-background" poster="images/poster.jpg">
```